# Eigenvalues of generalized Laplacian graph matrix

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory, spectral-radius, matrix-analysis

Consider a real matrix $A = [a_{ij}]_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. If

1. for any $i \neq j$, $a_{ij} \leq 0$, and
2. for any $1 \leq i \leq n$, $a_{ii} = -\sum_{j\neq i} a_{ij} \geq 0$,

is it true that $A$ can be diagonalized and has $n$ real eigenvalues
$0 = \lambda_1 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n$?

If matrix $A$ is symmetric, I know $A$ is the Laplacian matrix of a weighted undirected graph, and the above holds. I wonder if it is still true in general? Or can we say the real parts of the eigenvalues are all non-negative? I just feel this should be a well-studied problem...

(feel free to edit the title and the body of the question)

Comment: The Gershgorin circle theorem tells you that the real part is positive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve Thank you! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

As @AsAnExerciseProve has pointed, that all eigenvalues have non-negative real parts follows directly from [the Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).